# what steps should I take for not violating the adMob terms and conditions?

Tags: android, admob

I am beginner in using adMob so I want to know what steps should be taken so that I will not violate the adMob policies in future.

Please find my code below which I have followed:

## XML file which have adView :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

## onCreate of Activity which load's the ad.

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.banner_ad_layout);

        AdView adView=(AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
```

so now I want to know how can I enable live ad's when I upload my apk for production and how can I enable dummy ad's or test ad's during testing and development stage.

Please let me know the code changes I have to make during development and production.

Comment: @amit I went to their terms and conditions the most important thing is that publisher should not keep on clicking the ad's but as we develop the application it will be rigorously tested by testing team until it goes to production so I want to know is there any way that we can configure from code that I want live ad's even in development stage but when I click it should not consider as publisher has clicked it or it can invalidate that click

Comment: As far as I know, you can't configure anything from code to get live ad's during development, but their will be no problem in testing the development build.

Comment: @amit let me be clear on live ad's and demo ad's as of now I an using the same code to display the ad's that I have posted in by question and I am able to see some ad's like olx,askMe etc.. so they are live ad's if I am not wrong. so testers were clicking on that ad's as part of testing so that my adMob account has been blocked as publisher is clicking the ad's continuously so I just want to know is there any way that instead of these olx and etc.. ad's can I have some adMob demo ad's when I give build to the testers and I want to get live ad's like olx etc.. went we release it for producti.

Comment: For that you can use test_banner_id which you can very easily get from their samples and use that id for testing.

Comment: how to get that id can u please let me know is there any setting that need to be done in adMob when I register my application in Monetize tab(where i will get Ad unit Id) in adMob website.

Comment: For now, use this id- ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111.
For more detail, read this- https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: Thank you amit in the meanwhile I got another solution to get test ad's here is the following:AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("69AEF8955FAE39BFDF64CDB6D8911089").build(); is this the another alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Initially I used to click live ad's even during the development phase so my adMob account is blocked and not able to get any live ad's from adMob server so after some investigation I get to know how can i display some dummy ad's for testing and development stage.

Here is the answer for it:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
                "69AEF8955FAE39BFDF64CDB6D8911089").build();
```

use the above line of code during testing and development phase.Replace 69..... with the string that u find in your logcat when u run your application.

```
AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

use the above code during production phase,comment this during testing and development phase.